# how to attach sample of blackberry in phonegap in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to make application in blackberry in phonegap. But i don't know how to call wwww folder in blackberry screen. I am also install ant apache and I am try to using cmd it is possible but when i am attach sample and also phonegap library attach  in eclipse it is not working so how can i solved this problem please tell me .